Help with designing a battery charging circuit
I'm currently working on a circuit for simultaneously controlling and charging a battery. I'm using a USB Type-C for this circuit, which is separated into two 5V supply lines. The first line supplies voltage to the ESP32, and the second line charges the 18650 battery.
For charging, I'm using a TP4056 module, as shown in this circuit diagram:  
To clarify, the PMOS is used to turn off the supply to the boost converter (MT3608) whenever the USB-C is plugged in. When USB-C is not plugged in, the battery supplies power to the ESP32.
However, the circuit is not functioning correctly after assembling all the components, and I can't determine the issue because this is my first time working with this type of charging circuit.
Could someone please help me by offering advice on how to set up the battery charger and USB connection to work simultaneously? Thank you! The ESP32 circuit below works perfectly fine on its own without the battery connection.


It looks to me, as if the boost converter tries to charge the battery with the energy it takes from the same battery. Q3 must be an N-FET. Please provide more details about the issue, "does not work" could be anything.
